# how to remove extra line in excel from SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report name revenue. When i run the report, I get the desired result as per my development with row group. Problem is when I export this report data in excel, I get extra line added at each child row group which has garbage value.
Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: SSRS exports are pretty much a black box unless you're using the web service and programatically changing the output. Typically what you see is what you get - if you have any kind of aggregation on your child group(s) then you will get extra rows in Excel.

Comment: Hey Brain, I have export issue only in Excel. When I am exporting in PDF, Word, Tiff or XML, I get accurate data.

Comment: Can we get an image of your report and and image of excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting to CSV. This will remove the formatting and should provide a cleaner export to Excel.

Comment: Thanks Lucky for your input but If I export in CSV then i will lose formatting and parent grouping.